# scope resolution operator angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to use a scope resolution operator, like in c++, to use a parent $scope variable instead of the one in the current $scope.

I have two controllers, a Root ctrl and a Settings Ctrl. The Settings Ctrl is the child controller of Root ctrl so inherits it's variables. Both Controllers have a variable named $scope.users. Is there a way I can bypass this $scope.user in the settings ctrl(child controller) and use the one in the root ctrl (parent controller)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your child controller you can access the parent controller variable as

```
$scope.$parent.users
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, nested child controllers will automatically inherit scope variables from parent controllers. So in your child controller you could essentially access `$scope.someParentVariable`. Another alternative would be `$scope.parent.someParentVariable`.

I've made a quick CodePen to demonstrate.

http://codepen.io/oculusriff/pen/YpKaEW